# What is mvn default thread usage

Tags: performance, maven

What is mvn default thread usage? for example if I have 12 core system and if I run mvn "clean install" how maven allocate my CPU threads into entire build process?

Please advice.

Comment: I belive it is single. Take a look at the -T parameter when doing mvn -?

Comment: -T,--threads <arg>                     Thread count, for instance 2.0C
                                        where C is core multiplied

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking the same manner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default Maven uses a single thread due to backwards compatibility.

In Maven's official documentation [it is stated](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) that it is an experimental feature (as of Maven 3.0) that needs to be turned on selectively, because they cannot predict how existing plugins and specifically combinations of plugins behave with multiple threads; this might result in builds becoming non-reproducible.